Find the limit $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty } \int_0^k x^{-k} e^{x^2/k^2}\sin(x/k)~\mathrm dx$
Compute the limit$$\lim_{k \rightarrow  \infty }  \int_0^k x^{-k} e^{x^2/k^2}\sin(x/k)~\mathrm dx.$$
Completely stuck with this one. Some convergence theorem is obviously needed, but can't figure out which one and how to apply it.

Are you sure the integral is written correctly? We have $x^{-k} e^{x^2/k^2}\sin(x/k)\sim \frac{1}{k}x^{-k+1}$ as $x\to 0^+$ and $x^{-k+1}$ has a non-integrable singularity at $0$ for $k\geq 2$.

This is the way it is presented in the set of exercises I'm working on. There could be a mistake as I found basically the same exercise where $x^{-k}$ is replaced with $x^{-2}$ and the integral goes from 1 to infinity. This seems to make much more sense.
